# Notification Content Extension Header Height

Tags: swift, uikit, apple-push-notifications, notification-content-extension

How can the height of the 'Header' to a content extension be ascertained at run time (including the dismiss button)?

I have a content extension that lazy loads content, and then is dynamically resized by manipulating the preferredContentSize of the View Controller.

The content we need to show could be very long and tall, taller than the screen of the device. The content should not display past the edge of the screen, which would cause the user to scroll. If the content is long and tall we need to take into account the height of the content extension's header and dismiss button to calculate a content size that will fit on the screen. The sizing code could use a magic number for this height <104px, indicated by the red square in the included image>, but it would be better to dynamically calculate it.

From debugging, it's not clear what object I have access to at runtime that will allow me to find the origin of the Notification Content Extension View. Any ideas?

[image: Content Content Extension Header]